SSAS applying security to multiple Dimentions without considering facts
This is an example from AdventureWorks cube.
[Adventure Works Example]
enter image description here
I have below 5 dimensions SET 1:
Reseller,
Reseller Sales,
Territory,
Currency and Customer
which should be only accessible to the Role 1 : Users_Regional.
And then I have another set of 3 dimensions SET 2:
Date,
Product,
Promotion
which should be only accessible to the Role 2 : Users_Customer.
In either of the case, users from each of the Role, should not be able to access , dimensions from other category unless they are part of the both the roles.
For example, Users from, Role 1 : Users_Regional, Should not be able to access , SET 2 dimension information and Users from, Role 2 : Users_Customer, Should not be able to access , SET 1 dimension information .
Users, only if they are part of both the roles, Role 1 : Users_Regional and Role 2 : Users_Customer can access all the dimension information i.e. SET 1 and SET 2.
I can provide more info if needed.
Is it solvable or any better way of achieving this, or if any alternative solutions available can you please help me?
Thank you all for your support..
I know measure group security solutions. But I am not aware how can i add only dimension security for specific roles.
I have tried dimension security applied for measure groups.
Now I need to restrict entire set of dimensions for a specific roles.  And there are two roles , each of them have their open access to set of dimensions.

Welcome to Stack overflow and nice on having the courage to post.

Can you please make your question a little more succinct so the right people can help out. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
